# Is there a way to modify string format according to the max number of digits?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example, I have:

```
def MultTable(L,R):
    '''L and R are ranges'''
    lastL = L[len(L)-1]
    lastR = R[len(R)-1]
    digits1 = lastL //10
    digits2 = lastR //10
    for a in L:
        for b in R:
            print('{:3d}x{:3d}= {:3d}'.format(a, b, a*b))
```

```
    9   x   8   =   72
    9   x   9   =   81
    9   x   10  =   90
    10  x   8   =   80
    10  x   9   =   90
    10  x   10  =   100
    11  x   8   =   88
    11  x   9   =   99
    11  x   10  =   110
```

I have a code like this, but I can only print the code from a predetermined format.

How do we format the print function according to the max # of digits?

I have been trying to take the max number of digits from the list, but I can't seem to be able to apply it to the formatting.

Comment: You can create a format string on the fly, using old-fashioned formatting:  `fmt = "{:%dd}x{:%dd}= {:%dd}" % (digits, digits, digits)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First a format string is created with the dynamically calculated required number of digits, then the string is filled in with the desired values.

```
def MultTable(L, R):
    """L and R are ranges."""
    digitsL = len('{}'.format(L[-1]))
    digitsR = len('{}'.format(R[-1]))
    digitsProd = len('{}'.format(L[-1]*R[-1]))
    for a in L:
        for b in R:
            fs = '{{:{}d}} x {{:{}d}} = {{:{}d}}'.format(digitsL + 1, digitsR + 1, digitsProd + 1)
            print(fs.format(a, b, a*b))


MultTable(L=range(7,9), R=range(9,11))
print()
MultTable(L=range(99,101), R=(6,7))
```

Output like:

```
 7 x   9 =  63
 7 x  10 =  70
 8 x   9 =  72
 8 x  10 =  80

  99 x  6 =  594
  99 x  7 =  693
 100 x  6 =  600
 100 x  7 =  700
```